# Detect lock screen presence on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, lockscreen

I need some help in detecting lock screen from a custom credential provider running on  Windows 10. I believe Windows doesn't provide any APIs to detect lock screen presence. I'm currently using UI Automation to detect lock screen on Windows 8.1. However, it's not working on Windows 10. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx) to check if a particular user session is locked or not. Or use [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841.aspx) to receive [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828.aspx) notifications when sessions change state, including lock/unlock .

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I haven't performed much investigation, but there seems to be a difference between "screen" lock and "session" lock. On Win10/11 right after locking the screen (Win+L) nothing happens, but if a key is pressed or mouse button is clicked, password box appears and then the message arrives.